# Load this AJAX call on page load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'd like this AJAX call to load on page load. Right now I need to hit the refresh button for it to load.

Updated code:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#members", function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'data.php',
success: function(data) {    
$("#result").html(data).trigger('create');
$("#result").listview('refresh');
}
});
});
```

It loads correctly if I type in the page URL, but not when I go through my `index.php` file.

Comment: jQuery's `.ajax()` function _is_ doing an XMLHttpRequest call. Have you tried debugging with the console?

Comment: Don't use document.ready with jQuery Mobile. What you need instead is `$(document).on("pageinit","#pageid",function(){/* do the ajax here */});`

Comment: @KevinB - where did I miss the jQuery mobile mention?

Comment: It isn't mentioned, but he's using two constructs that are commonly used in jQuery mobile: `.trigger('create')` and `.listview('refresh')` Although, `.trigger('create')` is not in the current release version, so he's probably using an older version which doesn't guarantee he has a version of jQuery that supports `.on`. The problem he is having also describes exactly what would happen if he used document.ready instead of pageinit in jquery mobile.

Comment: Good way is to move the wrapped ajax stuff out of the function Ready  and define it as named function. Then, besides calling it in the function Ready, you would be able to use the function in another place, for example for cyclic calling (the you can refresh something automatic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
$("document")
```

should be

```
$(document)
```

because there are no `<document>` elements and if there were, you wouldn't be calling `.ready()` on them.

Next, the reason you are seeing this problem is because `$(document).ready()` only fires once per full page load. Changing to a new page in jQuery Mobile does not trigger a full page load, instead it loads in the new page with ajax. To get around this issue, jQuery mobile has an event called "pageinit" that gets triggered on the page that gets loaded in. This is how you would bind to it in your case:

pre-jquery 1.7

```
// yes, i know delegate is better, but the documentation specifically suggested using .live
$("#pageid").live("pageinit",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        success: function(data) {    
            $("#result").html(data).trigger('create');
            $("#result").listview('refresh');
        }
    });
});
```

post-jquery 1.7

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#pageid",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        success: function(data) {    
            $("#result").html(data).trigger('create');
            $("#result").listview('refresh');
        }
    });
});
```

The reason refreshing the page works is because when you refresh the page, the `$(document).ready()` event happens.

Comment: `$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler); `. This should be used as replacement of `live()` from `1.4.3` to Post `1.7`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both versions without success :(. I still need to hit refresh.

Comment: It loads correctly if I type in the page URL, but not when I go through my `index.php` file.

Comment: did you replace #pageid with a selector that will select the correct `data-role="page"` element?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the code in the original question above :)

Comment: is the element with `id="result"` unique? test with `alert( ($("[id=result]").length == 1 ? "IS" : "NOT") + " UNIQUE" );` It's easy to get duplicate ID's with how jQuery mobile works.

Comment: That gives me a "NOT UNIQUE" alert even if I rename `result`.

Comment: if you rename it it probably equals 0 which falsly gives a NOT. What's happening is you ahve another page in your document that currently is not active but contains an element with an id of #result. In jQuery Mobile, id's need to be unique application-wide, not just page-wide.

Comment: Ok! Renamed it to `id=population` but it still won't work. This is driving me crazy :)

Comment: BLAST! I had the code in the `<head>` and not `<body>`. Thank you for you help!